# suid executibles work only when present in the system PATH

Tags: linux, security, root, setuid, uid

I have an executible which requires root privilages. But it seems to work only when it's present in the system path. When I execute it like this:

```
$ ./prog
```

The program complains of having no root access. Looks like it's another security restriction on suid programs, but I've searched and I can't find anything related to it on the net. Why does it work like that? And is there an elegant way to do some testing on this program other than adding `.` to PATH, or calling `make` as root?

Edit: It doesn't work even when the current directory is in PATH.

Comment: What is the error message? and what is the output of `ls -ld ./prog`?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing whatsoever special about which pathname you use to invoke a program that can make a difference to whether or not its setuid bit will be honoured. It is certain that one of two things is happening here. Either

- the `prog` found in the `$PATH` and the `prog` found in the current directory are not in fact the same `prog`. Are you *sure* that `prog` alone is finding the same copy of `prog` via the `$PATH`?

  - (Exception: I can think of an unlikely edge case here where they might be the same file as in they are the same inode, but they are reached via different mount points, one of which has `nosuid` and one of which doesn't.)
- `prog` itself is consulting its `argv[0]` to see how it was invoked and is refusing to act on its setuid powers (or is dropping them) if it doesn't find what it expects.

Comment: The `$HOME/bin` and home partition are different on my pc and the bin folder mounts with `suid` option. And I've checked the source and the program starts arg parsing from position 1. And no, I don't have another copy of that program in my path.

Comment: The `prog` actually tries to read `/etc/shadow`, and complains if it's unsuccessful.